# Object instance as argument to JobIntentService

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building a temporary demo app and I need a service that polls a server every minutes. (I know there are better mechanisms for this). Now I have a class I call APIHandler that both my MainActivity and service should use. I have run into issues providing the service with the instance of my APIHandler class. So what I basically want here is my service to be able to use my APIHandler instance. The APIHandler class cannot be made static as it needs a Volley.newRequestQueue object which needs a context instance.

This is how I start my service from my MainActivity

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setup()
        apiHandler = APIHandler(this) //I neeed this instance...
        PollingService.enqueueWork(this, Intent(this, PollingService::class.java))
    }
```

This is my service

```
class PollingService(private val apiHandler: APIHandler) : JobIntentService() {
    private val timer = Timer()
    private val tag = "PollingService"
    //To be present here!

    companion object {
        fun  enqueueWork(context: Context, work: Intent) {
            enqueueWork(context, PollingService::class.java, 1, work)
        }
    }

    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        Log.d(tag, "Starting")
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask {
            run {
                Log.d(tag, "Polling...")
                apiHandler.getLEDState(1)
                apiHandler.getLEDState(2)
            }
        }, 0, 5000)
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        this.timer.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this an Android question?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the context, you can get it in the `onHandleWork` function, see below (sorry I'm using Java instead of Kotlin):

```
@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    // Instantiate your APIHandler with the context here
}
```

Try copy-pasting this into your project to have AS automatically convert it to Kotlin for you.